# Google sheet apps script Getvalues() get wrong value

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some help about get value form cell in Google Sheet but it get wrong value (I uesed getValues() with getRange("L13")) i don't know why it is like this and i don't know how to get a correct value

```js
function CalHP_Melee(){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var get_HP_Melee = sheet.getRange("B27").getValues();
 var get_HP_range_Melee = sheet.getRange("B27")
 var get_cal_atk_Melee = sheet.getRange("L13").getValues();
 var final_cal_hp_Melee = get_HP_Melee - get_cal_atk_Melee;

 if(get_cal_atk_Melee >= 0){ get_HP_range_Melee.setValues(final_cal_hp_Melee) }

}
```

image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfR9K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function CalHP_Melee(){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var get_HP_Melee = sheet.getRange("B27").getValue();
 var get_HP_range_Melee = sheet.getRange("B27")
 var get_cal_atk_Melee = sheet.getRange("L13").getValue();
 var final_cal_hp_Melee = get_HP_Melee - get_cal_atk_Melee;

 if(get_cal_atk_Melee >= 0){ get_HP_range_Melee.setValue(final_cal_hp_Melee) }

}
```

getValues() returns a two dimensional array getValue() returns a value.  You need to refer to the documentation too learn about what a method returns.